# Getting this error in C++, "no match for 'operator>>' in 'std:cin.std

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    using std::cout;
    using std::endl;
    using std::cin;
    short width;
    short legnth;
    short height;
    short volume;
    volume = (legnth * width * height);

    cout << "This program will determine the volume of a cube" << endl;
    cout << "Enter the legnth of the cube: ";
    cin >> legnth >> endl;
    cout << "Enter the width of the cube: ";
    cin >> width >> endl;
    cout << "Enter the height of the cube: ";
    cout << "Your volume is: " << volume;
    cout << "Press any key to exit :)";
    cin.get();

    return 0;
```

I am new to C++ and in my basic computer programming class we had to make something that can calculate volume, can someone please help me in fixing this error?

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`std::endl` is used for output stream not for input stream. I'd argue with that if it makes sense to a beginner, because you can put newline (and most of the time have to if you want to grab input from the user) into the input stream, but `std::endl` simply doesn't work with `std::cin`.

Besides I believe you don't really need to do it, because when you press "Enter" key to confirm your input newline character is also being printed to output stream.

Comment: THANKYOU!! My professor is moving WAY too fast for me! After 2 hours of just messing around with all the excersizes he told us to do, I finally got a jist of all the material he covered, but I was just stumped on that one error! I am sure if the professor actually taught efficiently and in chronological order, I would know how std::cin works, but unfortunately life doesnt always go the way you want it to, haha.

Answer (score 6):

You can't extract from `cin` to `endl` - that doesn't make any sense. You use `endl` with output streams to insert a newline and flush the stream. Just remove the `>> endl`s.

Also, you've spelled `length` incorrectly.